# Triggering resize of IFRAME returns the window width, not its with

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

there is a HTML:

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function() { alert ('resize: '+$(window).width()); } );
</script>
<iframe id = 'fr' src="/this" />

.
.
.
$('#fr').width(300).trigger('resize');
```

when resizing the IFRAME and triggering resize event, it alert the width of window, not the width of iframe. How to make the page "belive" that it is inside an IFRAME, and that is the window?

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to use `$(#fr).width();` not `$(window).width();`

Comment: yes, but the original page works with this already. Cant I say that IFRAME = Browser itself?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the width of the parent

```
$(this).parent().width()
```